# XCode/iOS Keep connection alive in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ftp, connection

In my app, I open a connection to use the iPad as a tiny FTP Server, then when the app runs, I can access to the app Documents with FileZilla, web browser, etc...

But can I keep this connection opened whe the app enter in background? I tried "Background Modes" but it doesn't work.

Thanks you all :)

EDIT : I use files from this project : https://github.com/sosoyososo/XZCodeBrowser

Answer (score 0):

The background modes in iOS are limited.  iOS devices are not designed to operate in the same way as a traditional computer, with multiple long-running tasks.  There are various background modes available, as you have investigated, that can help applications perform tasks in the background, but these are more focussed on the user experience (e.g. allowing an app to periodically fetch data or receive location updates) than running "servers".

Apps in the background are managed to reduce demand for memory and maximise battery life, so they can be unloaded at any time.

The VoIP background mode allows iOS to keep listening for network traffic on your app's behalf and re-launch your app in the background if necessary, but if you use this for a non-VoIP app I believe you will have problems with app approval.